# How to get pipreqs to skip files that fail to run

Tags: python

Many python files in my current project do not run / have syntax errors.

How can I get pipreqs to keep generating the requirements.txt, skipping those failures?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `pipreqs --force`.